# ElasticSearch Aggregations: subtracting aggregations based upon match

Tags: elasticsearch, analytics, aggregate

Using a simple albeit somewhat artificial example, let's say that I have several inventory docs stored in ElasticSearch where every document represents either the purchase or the sale of an item:

```
[
{item_id: "foobar", type: "cost", value: 12.34, timestamp:149382734621},
{item_id: "bizbaz", type: "sale", value: 45.12, timestamp:149383464621},
{item_id: "foobar", type: "sale", value: 32.74, timestamp:149384824621},
{item_id: "foobar", type: "cost", value: 12.34, timestamp:149387435621},
{item_id: "bizbaz", type: "sale", value: 45.12, timestamp:149388434621},
{item_id: "bizbaz", type: "cost", value: 41.23, timestamp:149389424621},
{item_id: "foobar", type: "sale", value: 32.74, timestamp:149389914621},
{item_id: "waahoo", type: "sale", value: 11.23, timestamp:149389914621},
...
]
```

And for a specified time range I want to calculate the current profit for each item. So for example I would want to return:

```
foobar_profit = sum(value of all documents item_id="foobar" and type="sale")
               -sum(value of all documents item_id="foobar" and type="cost")
bizbaz_profit = sum(value of all documents item_id="bizbaz" and type="sale")
               -sum(value of all documents item_id="bizbaz" and type="cost")
...
```

There are two aspects that I don't yet understand how to achieve.

1. I know how to [aggregate over terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), so this would allow me to sum the value of of all "foobar" items regardless of type. **But I don't know how to sum over all documents that match on two fields.** For instance, I want to aggregate the above data set on the compound key `(item_id,type)`. The dataset above would then yield the aggregations:

   - (foobar,cost)->24.68
   - (foobar,sale)->65.48
   - (bizbaz,cost)->41.23
   - (bizbaz,sale)->90.24
   - (waahoo,sale)->11.23
2. Presuming I can do #1, I will have aggregations like `foobar_cost` and `foobar_sale`. But I don't know how to combine two aggregations so that in this case `foobar_profit = foobar_sale - foobar_cost`. So the above aggregations would become

   - foobar_profit->40.8
   - bizbaz_profit->49.01
   - waahoo_profit->11.23

Some final notes:

- In the example above, I only list 3 item_ids, but consider that there will be thousands of item_ids, so I can't do special-case queries per item_id.
- Also, for a particular item, the `cost` and `sale` items will come in at different times, so we can't put the cost and sale price in the same document and diff the fields.
- I can send back all the data and do the last step of the aggregations client side, but this might be a ton of data. Really, I need to do it on server side if possible so that I can sort the results by *profit* and return the top N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use nested aggregations.  See here for a working example:  https://gist.github.com/mattweber/71033b1bf2ebed1afd8e

I use a MatchAll Query in this example but you can replace that with a RangeQuery or whatever you need.

Comment: Ohh and if you want to see some real power, you can use top level DateHistogram Aggregation that will calculate the date ranges for you!  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks for the example, though I want something just a step more complex than that. I've updated my example to clarify my goal (starting at "There are two aspects that I don't yet understand how to achieve" and down).

Comment: By the way, since I've started with a new company I've finally been able to dig into ES... really slick stuff. :-)

Comment: Ok, my answer covers #1.  I'm not sure #2 is possible, let me think about it.

Comment: I don't think #2 is possible at the moment but might be something we can get added.  I have opened an issue to track this at https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/5923.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I know the data structure is such that #2 shouldn't be hard. I guess the syntax just hasn't been devised yet.